# Linux command swapon and its unit

Tags: linux

I have a question.

What is the unit of the number which is shown when I type **swapon** with **-s** option. (in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on oracle VM vertualbox, type : 64-bit)

Namely when I type

```
$ sudo swapon -s

| Filename      | Type      | Size      | Used      | Priority      |
-
| /dev/sda5     | partition | 4192252   | 0         | -1            |
```

what is the unit of **4192252** ?

Note. 2^(20) = 4194304

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in kilobytes. 1,024 byte units.